# Can I install Ubuntu AMD/ATI Drivers on a Live CD/USB?

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati

The only way I can run Ubuntu Live CD is to put in `i915.modeset=0 xforcevesa`. It's because the open source drivers don't work on my graphics card. Is there a way to download AMD Drivers and install them on the live CD / USB?

Specifics:

- Graphics Card: AMD Radeon HD 6380G
- Laptop: HP Pavilion g6-1233sa

Answer (score 3):

I successfully installed the atidrivers on a live usb system.
First of all you need an empty stick - i used one with 16gb of space.
Put the live-cd in and install a system as u normally would install on an external hard drive.

Its neccessary that you use the instructions of method 1.

Then you already have a system with login on your usb stick.

Next you download the driver from AMD

Install the the driver the ubuntu way.

Its all tested with Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 version. If your getting problems let me know.

Because I am a new user I can't post more then 2 hyperlinks so I definitly would posted the complete solution.
But I will do a post on [my blog](http://chiefdome.wordpress.com/2012/08/16/amdati-drivers-on-ubuntu-12-04/) the next days.